# Is there anyway to hardcode a character in Java so that when I run the program between different platforms it still show up the same way?

Tags: java, windows, macos, unicode, character

I have been writing a mineSweeper program that uses square box character. According to [this website](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html), the character is `\u25A2` so when I test on my Macintosh Eclipse.

[image: screenshot]

In Mac, it shows up perfectly like the below half of the picture, but in Windows (the above half), the square shrinks!

Basically, I want to align the box with other characters that I use, but in Windows everything is just messed up. So I want to ask if there is anyway to bring these exact same characters from Macintosh and use it on every platforms?

Comment: That would depend on the font been used to display the character

Comment: Is there anyway I could check for that? I actually use an Model-View-Controller for this, do you guys need me to post the code for my View Class here?

Comment: *"Basically, I want to align the box with other characters that I use"* - Depending on the UI framework you're using, in `Swing` you could use `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`

Comment: actually, I am using character only and the box that I show in the picture is just a text area. I am novice but I believe the GridLayout is for button in general, not to a text area. I mean, for a mine sweeper program, I can create a grid of buttons but I am doing a task which requires me to use this particular MVC model. So I was wondering if there is anyway to just make sure when I export this program to *.jar it will bring over the exact characters from Mac to Windows? Thank you so much Mad

Comment: Why are you using **text characters** to represent such a grid?  Why not use real images, or even draw them in code?  Then you would not have these kind of issues.

Comment: Oh, I just need to stick with the MVC model in my class project which is really rudimentary. But thanks for the suggestion!